# Java Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize() ouputs are differently

Tags: java, awtrobot

```
    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getSize();
    System.out.println(d.width +"*"+d.height);

    PointerInfo pt = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    Dimension d2 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getSize();
    System.out.println(d2.width+"*"+d2.height);
```

First println result is 1536x864
but, second result is 1920x1080

I used the same code to getScreenSize(), but why do I get different results?
I only did MouseInfo.getPointerInfo() before print d2, but why d2 and d is diffrent??

And I calculated that 1536 and 1920 are 1.25 times different, so what means that 1.25 times  difference here?

Comment: I don't experience this problem.

Comment: I use JDK1.8. I've seen somewhere that this doesn't happen in version like JDK16

Comment: I also used JDK1.8.60